# VBA, referencing the name of another Sheet in Excel formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a cell with this formula, `=H4-'20200619'!H4` I need to change the formula daily.
`=H4-'nameAnotherSheet'!H4`

For Example, in the `C2` I want to store the name of another Sheet, with value `'nameAnotherSheet'`.

Now I need to do some thing like `=H4-'C2'!H4` but is not working!

**How, I do the reference of another name sheet in the formula?**

Now `C2` cell has the name Sheet.

`=H4-INDIRECT($C$2&"!H4")`.

Comment: `= H4 - INDIRECT("'" & $C$2 & "'!H4")`  Best to include the single-quotes in case the sheet name has spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to a sheet or address by its name

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet name!A1",TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you want to trigger it, or how to determine the sheet name each time, but since that isn't your question, here's how to treat a sheet name as a variable in your formula:

```
Range("A1").Formula = "=H4-'" & sSheetName & "'!H4"
```

If C2 has the name of the sheet....

```
Range("A1").Formula = "=H4-'" & Range("C2").Value & "'!H4"
```

Comment: Remember, The name Now is in the `C2` Cell, how to use it in the formula?

Comment: You just change the `H4` you want to `C2` - or am i missing something?

Comment: The name of the sheet is C2? Your question is very confusing...

Comment: =H4-INDIRECT($C$2&"!H4"), C2 has the name Sheet.